# Ios App working when installed from Xcode on iphone 5S but not when installed from App Store

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm having a problem when installing my app from the app store, the camera doesn't work on Iphone 5S, ONLY on Iphone 5S the weird thing is that it does work on the other iphones and IT WORKS on Iphone 5S when installed from the Xcode, it's the same version I checked.
The bug appears in the Camera, I'm using AVCaptureSession to show the camera  and this is the code that I'm using to capture the picture.

```
// Capture the image
- (void) capImage {
    AVCaptureConnection *videoConnection = nil;
    for (AVCaptureConnection *connection in stillImageOutput.connections) {

        for (AVCaptureInputPort *port in [connection inputPorts]) {

            if ([[port mediaType] isEqual:AVMediaTypeVideo] ) {
                videoConnection = connection;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (videoConnection) {
            break;
        }
    }

    NSLog(@"about to request a capture from: %@", stillImageOutput);

    [stillImageOutput captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection:videoConnection completionHandler: ^(CMSampleBufferRef imageSampleBuffer, NSError *error) {

        if (imageSampleBuffer != NULL) {

        NSData *imageData = [AVCaptureStillImageOutput jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation:(imageSampleBuffer)];

            self.imagenCamara.image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
            imageSampleBuffer = nil;
            imageData = nil;
        }
    }];
}
```

Oh, the bug is only the camera, everything else in the app works, only it doesn't capture the pic, it stays gray when the pic is taken
I can't seem to find the problem, I don't make sense of it only NOT working on iphone 5S when installed from App Store but working when installed from Xcode.

Comment: I'm not sure what's wrong, but if it helps debugging you could archive and export using a development certificate and install the signed .ipa onto your device using the `window/devices` menu in Xcode.